# Replace associative element in each row with the associative grandchild of the unwanted parent element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace, associative-array

I need to restructure a multidimensional array in a Drupal application.

[image]

Here is full image:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/array.png/

`field_new => [...]` has to become `'value' => '11111'`

Comment: Please try to add actual output in text form instead of images. That said, All I can see is that `filed_new(Arr...)` is not there in your output. So, do you just want to delete it?

Comment: filed_new(Arr...) has to become ['value'] = string (11111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Input Array:**

```
...
0{
    data{
        nid => 1
        vid => 1
        type => article
        field_new{
            und{
                0{
                    value => 11111
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
1{
    data{
        nid => 2
        vid => 2
        type => article
        field_new{
            und{
                0{
                    value => 33333
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Your desired array:**

```
...
0{
    data{
        nid => 1
        vid => 1
        type => article
        value => 11111
    }
}
1{
    data{
        nid => 2
        vid => 2
        type => article
        value => 33333
    }
}
```

[**Unset** (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) is our friend.

> unset() destroys the specified variables.

**Use this code:**

```
<?php

$loop_count = count($input_arr);
for($i=0;$i<loop_count;$i++){
    //copy the value to the desired place
    $input_arr[$i]["data"]["value"] = $input_arr[$i]["data"]["field_new"]["und"][0]["value"];

    //delete the unwanted portion
    unset($input_arr[$i]["data"]["field_new"]);
} // for loops ENDS

?>
```

**Assumptions:**

- Your base/parent array is numerically indexed.
- In each array, field_new is at same level.

Please add the code you are using you to produce/get this array, and we could provide you more specific answers.

Comment: thanks `$arr[$i]["data"]["value"] = $arr[$i]["data"]["field_new"]['und']['0']["value"];` worked instead of `$input_arr[$i]["data"]["value"] = $input_arr[$i]["data"]["field_new"]["value"];` but again, thanks i've been looking for this for whole morning :)

Comment: @punked Sorry, my bad! Updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend directly modifying the input array by using array destructuring syntax to isolate the `data` subarray as a reference variable, then declare the `value` to be the deepest scalar value of `field_new`.

Code: [(Demo)](https://3v4l.org/mbUa4)

```
foreach ($array as ['data' => &$data]) { 
    $data['value'] = $data['field_new']['und'][0]['value'];
    unset($data['field_new']);
}
var_export($array);
```